# import complex Json data to hive

Tags: json, hadoop, import, hive, bigdata

A little spoon feeding required, how to import complex json into hive. Json file in the format of:`{"some-headers":"", "dump":[{"item-id":"item-1"},{"item-id":"item-2"},...]}`.
Hive to have fields given under `dump`. Json file size, as now ,is not exceeding 200MB, but since its a dump, it will reach GBs very soon. Any other possible methods shall be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import JSON into Hive by implementing the HiveSerDe.

This link serves as a sample implementation.

https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

You can also refer to these links

[How do you make a HIVE table out of JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479247/how-do-you-make-a-hive-table-out-of-json-data)

Comment: Hi,
Is there any possibility of updating any record in such hive table using UPDATE command of hive?

Answer (score 2):

posting End-to-End solution. Step by step procedure to convert JSON to hive table:

step 1)  install maven if not there already

`>$ sudo apt-get install maven`

step 2) install git if not there already

`>sudo git clone https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde.git`

step 3) go into the $HOME/HIVE-JSON_Serde folder

step 4) build the serde package

`>sudo mvn -Pcdh5 clean package`

step 5) The serde file will be in 
   **$HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

step 6) Add serde as dependency jar in hive

```
 hive> ADD JAR $HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7- SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

step 7) create json file in $HOME/books.json (Example)

```
{"value": [{"id": "1","bookname": "A","properties": {"subscription": "1year","unit": "3"}},{"id": "2","bookname":"B","properties":{"subscription": "2years","unit": "5"}}]}
```

step 8) create tmp1 table in hive

```
 hive>CREATE TABLE tmp1 (
      value ARRAY<struct<id:string,bookname:string,properties:struct<subscription:string,unit:string>>>   
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
    'mapping.value' = 'value'   
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

step 9) load the data from json to tmp1 table

```
>LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '$HOME/books.json' INTO TABLE tmp1;
```

step 10) create a tmp2 table to do explode operation form tmp1, this intermediate step is to break multi level json structure into multiple rows 
Note: if your JSON structure is simple and single level , avoid this step

```
hive>create table tmp2 as 
 SELECT *
 FROM tmp1
 LATERAL VIEW explode(value) itemTable AS items;
```

step 11) create hive table and load the values from tmp2 table

```
hive>create table books as 
select value[0].id as id, value[0].bookname as name, value[0].properties.subscription as subscription, value[0].properties.unit as unit from tmp2;
```

step 12) drop tmp tables

```
hive>drop table tmp1;
hive>drop table tmp2;
```

step 13) test the hive table

```
hive>select * from books;
```

output:

id name subscription unit

1 B 1year 3

2 B 2years 5

Comment: "Step 11" should be :

    create table books as 
    select items.id as id, items.bookname as name, items.properties.subscription as subscription, items.properties.unit as unit from tmp2;

Comment: Is there any possibility of updating any record in such hive table using UPDATE command of hive?