# Hive query for nested json

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I stored following json in hive

```
 {"key":123,"c1":["s1","s2","s3"],"c2":{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}}
 {"key":456,"c1":["s4","s5","s6"],"c2":{"k3":"v3","k4":"v4"}}
```

Now I want a query of given hive json so I will get following output
output:

`key c1 c1 c1 c2 c2 c2 c2 
 123 s1 s2 s3 k1 v1 k2 v2
 456 s4 s5 s6 k3 v3 k4 v4`

So how is possible in hive or I missing my output structure?

Comment: What create table statement you tried ?

Comment: @MukeshS I was used mongo hive conversion using below link
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/hive
so I used my mongo douments in hive.

Comment: Well I am sorry but I have not worked on mongodb so can't help you much. I thought you are using just Hive and Json.

Comment: Hope my reply in this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/38727609/6668328

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Brickhouse JSON UDFS ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) to parse the JSON into Hive structures, and then access the values.

```
SELECT strct.key,
       strct.c1[ 0 ], strct.c1[1], strct.c1[2],
       map_keys( strct.c2 )[ 0 ], map_values( strct.c2)[0],   
       map_keys( strct.c2 )[ 1 ], map_values( strct.c2)[1]
FROM (
  SELECT from_json( json_str, 
        named_struct("key", 0, "c1", array(""), "c2", map("","") )) as strict
  FROM json_table
) js;
```

Read the Brickhouse confessions  blog posting for more  info at http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/ .

Answer (score -1):

posting End-to-End solution. Step by step procedure to convert JSON to hive table:

step 1)  install maven if not there already

`>$ sudo apt-get install maven`

step 2) install git if not there already

`>sudo git clone https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde.git`

step 3) go into the $HOME/HIVE-JSON_Serde folder

step 4) build the serde package

`>sudo mvn -Pcdh5 clean package`

step 5) The serde file will be in 
   **$HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

step 6) Add serde as dependency jar in hive

```
 hive> ADD JAR $HOME/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7- SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

step 7) create json file in $HOME/books.json (Example)

```
{"value": [{"id": "1","bookname": "A","properties": {"subscription": "1year","unit": "3"}},{"id": "2","bookname":"B","properties":{"subscription": "2years","unit": "5"}}]}
```

step 8) create tmp1 table in hive

```
 hive>CREATE TABLE tmp1 (
      value ARRAY<struct<id:string,bookname:string,properties:struct<subscription:string,unit:string>>>   
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
    'mapping.value' = 'value'   
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

step 9) load the data from json to tmp1 table

```
>LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '$HOME/books.json' INTO TABLE tmp1;
```

step 10) create a tmp2 table to do explode operation form tmp1, this intermediate step is to break multi level json structure into multiple rows 
Note: if your JSON structure is simple and single level , avoid this step

```
hive>create table tmp2 as 
 SELECT *
 FROM tmp1
 LATERAL VIEW explode(value) itemTable AS items;
```

step 11) create hive table and load the values from tmp2 table

```
hive>create table books as 
select value[0].id as id, value[0].bookname as name, value[0].properties.subscription as subscription, value[0].properties.unit as unit from tmp2;
```

step 12) drop tmp tables

```
hive>drop table tmp1;
hive>drop table tmp2;
```

step 13) test the hive table

```
hive>select * from books;
```

output:

id name subscription unit

1 B 1year 3

2 B 2years 5