# Store Pig result into Hive table using Hcat - ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I want to load the simple json data into hive table without using Json Serde.

So I have tried to Load the json file in Pig and store the result into hive table.

```
A = LOAD '/data/pig_files/test.json' Using JsonLoader('merchant_id: chararray, platform_id: chararray, last_cdd_review_date: chararray, risk_factors:{(area:chararray,risk:chararray)}, expected_annual_transaction_number: chararray');

STORE A INTO 'Test_tbl' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

It works fine but after server patching getting below error

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1115: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2001 : 
Error setting output information. Cause : 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias A
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1779)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:708)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1110)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:512)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:227)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.plan.VisitorException: ERROR 1115: <line 3, column 0> Output Location Validation Failed for: 'test_tbl More info to follow:
org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2001 : Error setting output information. 
Cause : com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.java:64)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:99)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan.validate(LogicalPlan.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.compile(PigServer.java:1852)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$300(PigServer.java:1528)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1441)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$500(PigServer.java:119)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1774)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1115: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2001 : 
Error setting output information. Cause : com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer.setStoreLocation(HCatStorer.java:196)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidatorVisitor.java:57)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2001 : Error setting output information. Cause : 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(HCatOutputFormat.java:220)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(HCatOutputFormat.java:70)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer.setStoreLocation(HCatStorer.java:191)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2263)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:229)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:204)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveMetastoreClient(HCatUtil.java:563)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(HCatOutputFormat.java:90)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:234)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:229)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1773)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/NucleusContext
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getClass(MetaStoreUtils.java:1741)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:688)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:7036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:254)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:334)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 64 more
================================================================================
```

Help me to resolve this or suggest me other ways to load Json data into hive table without Serde.

Comment: 1) You need a serde 2) Does the command `pig classpath` return anything? Can you show it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - pig classpath error updated above question.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking `hadoop classpath`. But basically the error is saying you're missing a JAR.  Maybe the core one from here ... https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus

Comment: Alternatively, use Spark instead of Hive. Or just copy the JSON file into HDFS and simply build the JSON table there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479247/how-do-you-make-a-hive-table-out-of-json-data